# How do I access the render :layout option in a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

I would like to have classes in my HTML body tag that represent the current layout, controller and action.

```
<body class="my_layout controller action">

def body_classes
  "layout_#{controller.class.send(:_layout) || :application} #{params[:controller]} #{params[:action]}"
end
```

This is for CSS styling purposes.

I can't find a way to access the layout information reliably. `controller.class.send(:_layout)` will access the layout, but only if it's defined in the class with `layout :layout`, not if it's defined in the render call:

```
render layout: x || y
```

My layouts can be dynamic...

How can I access the layout name when passed as `render layout: layout`?